# Google Sheets - QUERY, adding a cell to hide a row

Tags: sorting, select, google-sheets

I'm hoping to use a Google Form to have my students sign up for activities.  I added a column to the right of the form data where I can put an "x" once I have met with them.  I have a separate tab called "Ordered" where I use QUERY to sort and show only the entries without an x.  Once I meet with a student, I can put an x on the original data tab, and the entry will hide from the Ordered tab (kind of a queue for my students).

I would love to not have to switch between the 2 tabs every time I have to check someone off.  Is there a way to add a similar column on the Ordered tab that will hide the finished entry?

Here is the sheet I'm referring to:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fQHF0EoGLk5NEI6GvyRk4InBl-uEq0jq7qqmyOmFjy8/edit#gid=379798836

I'm sharing this sheet with other teachers who aren't familiar with spreadsheets, so the solution has to be ludite friendly.

Comment: You will likely run into circular dependency issues if you try passing values to F from within the queried range. Have you tried writing something with Apps Script? The other teachers don't need to understand the code.

Comment: Yeah, I've run into circular dependencies... 

I'll have to think about Apps Script.  Not sure where to start with that...

Comment: You can start by reading the guides in the documentation, and doing some "5-min" quickstarts. See [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#get_started) & [Apps Script overview](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer regarding this, I hope this is helpful to you :)

Answer (score 1):

As @Aerials said, you are likely to run into circular dependency issues here. Because of this, I'd suggest using Apps Script and get rid of the `QUERY` formula. You want to do the following:

- Every time someone submits the form, the `Ordered` sheet gets updated with the new submission data.
- Every time an `x` is added to the `Form Responses 1` sheet, the corresponding row in `Ordered` gets removed.
- Every time an `x` is added to the `Ordered` sheet, the corresponding row in `Ordered` gets removed, and an `x` gets added to the corresponding row in `Form Responses 1`.

A possible way to go would be something along the following lines (open the script bound to your spreadsheet by clicking `Tools > Script editor`):

- Install an [onFormSubmit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onFormSubmit()) so that `Ordered` gets updated with new data every time the form is submitted. The trigger can be installed [manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) or programmatically, copying this function to your script and running it once:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("copyAndFilterData")
  .forSpreadsheet(ss)
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();
}
```

- Once the trigger is installed, the function `copyAndFilterData` will execute every time the form is submitted. This function should updated `Ordered` based on the data in `Form Responses 1`, removing all the submission that have been marked as complete `x`. This function could be the following:

```
function copyAndFilterData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Ordered");
  var sourceData = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var filteredData = sourceData.filter(sourceRow => sourceRow[5] !== "x")
  .sort((a, b) => a - b)    
  .map(sourceRow => {
       sourceRow.pop();
       sourceRow.splice(1, 1);
       return sourceRow;
  });
  sheet2.getRange(1, 1, sheet2.getLastRow(), 4).clear({contentsOnly: true});
  var destRange = sheet2.getRange(1, 1, filteredData.length, filteredData[0].length)
  destRange.setValues(filteredData);
}
```

- At this point, another piece of functionality would be needed: update the spreadsheet based on the addition or removal of `x` on any of both sheets. For this, an [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger would be needed, like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var editedSheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (editedSheet.getName() === "Form Responses 1") copyAndFilterData();
  else if (editedSheet.getName() === "Ordered") removeRows(e, editedSheet);
}
```

- Once this function is copied and the project saved, every time `Form Responses 1` is edited, the `Ordered` sheets gets updated (function `copyAndFilterData`), and every time `Ordered` is edited, the function `removeRows` is fired. This function should do two things: (1) remove the row which was marked as complete in `Ordered` (`x` added) and (2) add the corresponding `x` to `Form Responses 1`. The submission dates can be compared to identify the row:

```
function removeRows(e, editedSheet) {
  var range = e.range;
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var value = range.getValue();
  if (column == 5 && row > 1 && value == "x") {
    var date = editedSheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
    var formSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1")
    var values = formSheet.getRange(2, 1, formSheet.getLastRow() - 1).getValues(); 
    var markedRow = values.findIndex(value => value[0].getTime() === date.getTime());
    formSheet.getRange(markedRow + 2, 6).setValue("x");
    editedSheet.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Overview of Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)
- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)